# Filter unique lines

Tags: perl, awk

I have a tile type called fasta which contains a header "> 12122" followed by a string. I would like to remove duplicated strings in the file and keep only one of the duplicated string (same which) and the corresponding header.
In the example below the AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC is duplicated

in:

```
>17-46151
AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
>1-242
AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
>18-41148
TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
>43-16054
GTCCCACTCCGTAGATCTGTTC
>32-24116
TAGCATATCGAGCCTGAGAACA
>42-16312
TGATACGGATGTTATACGCAGC
```

out:

```
>1-242
AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
>18-41148
TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
>43-16054
GTCCCACTCCGTAGATCTGTTC
>32-24116
TAGCATATCGAGCCTGAGAACA
>42-16312
TGATACGGATGTTATACGCAGC
```

Comment: Why do you keep `18-41148`? It seems not to be duplicated

Comment: Sorry, I want to keep unique strings. If one is duplicated I want to keep one of the duplicates

Comment: You could try use a Perl hash for exampl: `perl -nE 'chomp;chomp($seq=<>);$seqs{$seq}=$_; END {for (keys %seqs) {say ; say $seqs{$_}}}' in.txt`

Comment: What did you try, and what problems are you having? It would be better if you could show us some code so we can help with what's not working, instead of coming here and asking us to write your code.

Comment: you can use `bioperl` for this http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.007001/BioPerl.pm

Answer (score 0):

if order is mandatory

```
# Field are delimited by new line
awk -F "\n" '
   BEGIN { 
      # Record is delimited by ">"
      RS = ">"
      }
   # skip first "record" due to first ">"
   NR > 1 {
      # if string is not know, add it to "Order" list array
      if ( ! (  $2 in L ) ) O[++a] = $2
      # remember (last) peer label/string
      L[$2] = $1
      }
   # after readiong the file
   END{
      # display each (last know) peer based on the order
      for ( i=1; i<=a; i++ ) printf( ">%s\n%s\n", L[O[i]], O[i])
      }
  ' YourFile
```

if order is not mandatory

```
awk -F "\n" 'BEGIN{RS=">"}NR>1{L[$2]=$1}END{for (l in L) printf( ">%s\n%s\n", L[l], l)}' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{if(NR%2) p=$0; else a[$0]=p}END{for(i in a)print a[i] ORS i}' file
>18-41148
TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
>32-24116
TAGCATATCGAGCCTGAGAACA
>1-242
AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
>43-16054
GTCCCACTCCGTAGATCTGTTC
>42-16312
TGATACGGATGTTATACGCAGC
```

Explained:

```
{
    if(NR%2)             # every first (of 2) line in p
        p=$0
    else                 # every second line is the hash key
        a[$0]=p
}
END{
    for(i in a)          # output every unique key and it's header
        print a[i] ORS i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick one-line awk solution for you. It should be more immediate than the other answers because it runs line by line rather than queuing the data (and looping through it) until the end:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 && !seen[$0]++ { print last; print } { last = $0 }' file
```

Explanation:

- `NR % 2 == 0` runs only on even numbered records (lines, `NR`)
- `!seen[$0]++` stores and increments values and returns true only when there were no values in the `seen[]` hash (`!0` is 1, `!1` is 0, `!2` is 0, etc.)
- (Skipping to the end) `last` is set to the value of each line after we're otherwise done with it
- `{ print last; print }` will print `last` (the header) and then the current line (gene code)

Note: while this preserves the original order, it shows the *first* uniquely seen instance while the expected output showed the *final* uniquely seen instance:

```
>17-46151
AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
>18-41148
TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
>43-16054
GTCCCACTCCGTAGATCTGTTC
>32-24116
TAGCATATCGAGCCTGAGAACA
>42-16312
TGATACGGATGTTATACGCAGC
```

If you want the final uniquely seen instance, you can reverse the file before passing to awk and then reverse it back afterwards:

```
tac file |awk … |tac
```